# CakePHP, How to getting value from another table

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, joincolumn

I have 2 table on model , Table1 and Table2
Column on Table1

```
ID | Content1
```

Column on Table2

```
ID | table1_id | Content2
```

i want to display Content in Table1 on Table2 , how to join column?

thanks advance!

Comment: You question is not clear. Also post your so far tried code.

Comment: Use find query and try to use Contain.. But the Question you asked is not clear. Need more info to help you

Comment: Do you want to join the result of both tables ?

Comment: i actually resolve this problem rightnow :D thanks anyway for replied..
it simple.. i just put this on my source code                                                                        
public $belongsTo = array('Goods' => array('className'=>'Goods','foreignKey'=>'goods_id','dependent'=>true));
:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Model\Model1.php`

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Model1 extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'table1';

}
```

`Model\Model2.php`

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Model2 extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'table2';

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Model1' => array(
            'className' => 'Model1',
            'foreignKey' => 'table1_id'
        )
    );

}
```

In the controller:

```
$data = $this->Model2->find('all');
```

The generated query will be

```
SELECT `Model2`.`id`, `Model2`.`table1_id`, `Model2`.`content2`, `Model1`.`id`, `Model1`.`content1` FROM `db`.`table2` AS `Model2` LEFT JOIN `cake244`.`table1` AS `Model1` ON (`Model2`.`table1_id` = `Model1`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1
```